# Alternative to labeled loops

Tags: typescript

I'm adding objects to a collection inside a for-loop, like this (`points` is a `Point[]`):

```
for (const point of points) {
    // do and check some stuff
    collection.push(point)
}
```

I then realized I needed objects to be unique, but since they're of a custom type, I can't use a `Set<Point>`, which doesn't use the objects' `equals` function to compare them. My naive approach was checking each of the already assigned objects, which is fine performance-wise since the collection is usually very small:

```
addPoints: for (const point of points) {
    // do and check some stuff
    for (const existingPoint of collection) {
        if (point.equals(existingPoint)) break addPoints
    }
    collection.push(point)
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `break label` construct here in order to break out of my outer loop in case I encounter a point I've already added to the collection.

My linter doesn't like this, throwing a "[no-labels](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-labels)" violation, whose description states

> While convenient in some cases, labels tend to be used only rarely and are frowned upon by some as a remedial form of flow control that is more error prone and harder to understand.

My question is: **How can I handle this use case without adding unnecessary complexity?**

Things I've considered, but dislike because they add lots of code that feels unnecessarily clunky *compared to the label*:

- Moving the check into a separate function, which is essentially the inner loop, then call that with a simple `if - break` in my outer loop.
- Setting a flag in the inner loop, then checking that in the outer loop in order to `break` out.
- Writing a whole wrapper class for my collection that uses `equals` to check for unique members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```js
for (const point of points) {
  const alreadyExists = collection.some(
    (p) => p.x === point.x && p.y === point.y
  );

  if (!alreadyExists) {
    collection.push(point);
  }
}
```

With `some` function you can write your own comparator and check the object equality with any rule you need

Comment: That's essentially my Set problem. `includes` internally uses either `===` or some kind of reference-based thing, rather than the objects' `equals` functions, so it won't correctly recognize different instances of an object representing the same point.

Comment: @scenia My bad, updated an answer

Comment: @scenia did this help?

Comment: `some` works great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `Map` for things like this, and define the map keys as e.g. strings that make out unique elements:

```
const map = new Map<string, Point>();

for (const point of points) {
    const key = ...
    map.set(key, point);
}

const collection = [...map.values()];
```

This requires that you can build a key from the point attributes that uniquely define a point. You didn't include your `Point` interface, but if it's a point in space and has `x` and `y` properties, you could e.g. do `map.set([point.x, point.y].join(';'), point)`, `map.set(JSON.stringify(point), point)` or whatever suits your needs.